# Redirect back to original page

Tags: redirect, clojure, compojure

Given some compojure routes:

```
(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/" [] (display-some-html))
  (GET "/story" [] (display-more-html))
  (GET "/classes" [] (display-other-html))
  (POST "/delete" [id] (do (delete-some-id-from-db id)
                           (magic-redirect-function)))
  (route/resources "/")
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))
```

Suppose I am able to POST to `/delete` from `/`, `/story`, `/classes`. How would I redirect to the page that the POST request originated from?

Comment: Every time you use POST for DELETE operations, a kitten dies. You could also include in the POST request the URL to redirect to (i.e. the URL of the current page) and then use it in a call to `ring.util.response/redirect` as deadghost answer demoes.

Comment: @schaueho POST changed to DELETE in my actual code. Including the redirect url in the request is a good solution as well, though right now session + middleware solution looks cleanest.

Comment: One potential issue with session - there is an assumption that requests come in sequence. If they come in parallel - say if user has a few tabs in the same browser open - the user can be redirected to an unexpected page. The solution where the resirect url is included in delete request does not have that particular problem.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way is to have the previous url in your session, and redirect the user there / render the corresponding view after your operation. If you're using the [site handler](http://weavejester.github.io/compojure/compojure.handler.html), you already have wrap-session included.

You could do something similar to this example from the [Ring wiki](https://github.com/mmcgrana/ring/wiki/Sessions), it's trivial to change it to store the request path instead of a count.

```
(defn handler [{session :session}]
  (let [count   (:count session 0)
        session (assoc session :count (inc count))]
    (-> (response (str "You accessed this page " count " times."))
        (assoc :session session))))
```

Comment: This answer is good, but maybe it should also include the details of the redirect function needed?

Answer (score 1):

Use Referrer header to redirect back

```
(let [back (get (:headers request) "referer")]
  (redirect-to back))
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution based on Diego's suggestion using `lib-noir`.

```
(ns my-project.handler
    (:require (compojure [handler :as handler]
                         [route :as route]
                         [core :refer :all])
              [ring.util.response :refer [redirect]]
              [noir.util.middleware :as middleware]
              [noir.session :as session]))

(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/" [] 
       (session/put! :origin "/")
       (display-some-html))
  (GET "/story" [] 
       (session/put! :origin "/story")
       (display-more-html))
  (GET "/classes" [] 
       (session/put! :origin "/classes")
       (display-other-html))
  (POST "/delete" [id] 
        (delete-some-id-from-db id)
        (redirect (session/get! :origin "/"))) ; "/" is an optional default
  (route/resources "/")
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (-> 
   (handler/site app-routes)
    session/wrap-noir-session))
```

It works but I wouldn't call it elegant.

Comment: You could write a middleware to encapsulate the session/put part if you plan to reuse it in many routes. Three is probably ok for code repetition. Also, you can put all the expressions in your do in separate lines. That will make them indent properly without unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion by deadghost is the best one. Here you can find my solution to getting automatic redirects to your main page using the lib-noir library. I hope this helps someone.

```
    (ns hue-web-app.core
    (:require   [ring.middleware.defaults :refer [wrap-defaults api-        defaults site-defaults]]
                [ring.util.response :as response]        ;;from ring
                [compojure.core :refer :all]
                [compojure.route :as route]            
                [noir.util.middleware :as middleware]
                [noir.session :as session]]  ;;noir for redirect to work

    (defroutes hue-app-routes
      (GET "/" [] (session/put! :origin "/")
                  (io/file "resources/testsite.html"))
      (GET "/turn-off" [] (turn-group-off 3 user) 
                          (response/redirect (session/get! :origin "/")))
      (GET "/turn-on" [] (turn-group-on 3 user)
                         (response/redirect (session/get! :origin "/"))))

    ;;STARTING THE SERVER
    ;;--------------------------------------------------------------        ------------
    (defn siteparams
      []
      (run-jetty (-> #'hue-app-routes
                     wrap-reload
                     wrap-restful-format
                     wrap-params
                     session/wrap-noir-session
                     )
                 {:port 5003
                  :join? false}))
```